# После обновления TypeScript до 4.9 не работает оператор satisfies

Tags: javascript, typescript, синтаксис, typescript-типы

После апгрейда до версии 4.9 TypeScript не получается протестировать возможности нового оператора satisfies.
Якобы синтаксическая ошибка в коде (скриншоты прилагаю) (Newline or semicolon expected). При этом в JSONе версия 4.9, в настройках IDE также отображается 4.9.

Что делаю не так?
[image: error]

[image: error2]

[image: error3]

[image: error4]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: работает же, https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzHAdhFwDSERQLxQDkAxosmhgIyFQA+RpSq6wATDfSWcxgMyEBuALAAoUigDOwKABMAhsDn4oAb1FQNURuRaUAXFAAMAGnWbtPNgcKFTIzVu4VgvAwBZWdgL5QJCgJYSAGb+EBJQAEoQpABOMgA88EzO2CDGUCgArggARhAxdL7AMf4oAOYAfAJAA